# Override an import statement to point to a custom package

Tags: javascript

when importing a javascript module along the lines of

```
{
  import {Widget} from "[some-path]/widget";
}
```

Is it possible to register, or configure it such that I could make a package that I want to replace the existing widget package without having to go and change all the various modules that import this Widget?

```
{
  const BetterWidget = () => { ...//my cool code};
}
```

So if anyone imports the original widget, they get my shinny new one?

I realize there are serious ramifications to doing this, but I am wondering if there is a pattern for achieving it in javascript?

Comment: If it's built with something like Webpack, I think so. Otherwise, you'd need server-side URL rewriting, I think, which is possible but really really strange. Better option: replace the `[some-path]/widget` with the new widget

Comment: all you have to do to override an existing imported class is import yours afterwards.  It will replace identical functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript itself doesn't define anything that lets you do that, no, not least because JavaScript itself doesn't specify the content of import specifiers at all; just that they're strings that the host should use to resolve modules.

Some bundlers do. Webpack, for instance, lets you "alias" modules in your Webpack configuration. This is used to great effect to (for instance) use Preact instead of React while still using modules that expect to work with React. I don't know whether it's possible to do it when the import specifier has a path, though, as opposed to being a raw specifier (`"widget"`) that Webpack is already expected to resolve.

Similarly, on browsers, the [import maps](https://wicg.github.io/import-maps/) proposal will enable raw specifiers on browsers, which then get resolved through the import map; and thus your page can say that `"widget"` is really `"./nifty-shiny-new-widget.js"`.